# I can't access the chrome:settings and other chrome: and about: urls un Google Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android

Although google chrome does suggest those urls:

[image: image description]

It doesn't allow you to access them:

[image: image description]

I'm very upset, since I am forced to use Chrome (it's pre-installed and takes 100MB) but I can't even access full configuration.

Comment: The mobile version of Google Chrome does *not* have any major configuration other than using the dot-menu/menu button to access settings and `chrome://flags`.

Answer (score 1):

You can view full list of supported `chrome:` URLs on `chrome://chrome-urls` page. Note that the lists are different for the Android and desktop versions. In particular, there is no `chrome://settings` in Android version because there the settings are implemented using native OS forms.